# perl6 Catching non-fatal exceptions in autovivification

Tags: exception, raku, autovivification

I am running analysis on about 10000 lines of numbers, and some of the lines give me errors: "Use of uninitialized value of type Any in numeric context". I am trying to catch this error to see which lines are causing the problem. However, the X::TypeCheck, and other X::* classes don't seem to do effective catching autovivification of Nil or Any. E.g.:

```
try { say Any + 1; CATCH { default { say "oh-no"; } }; }
```

still gives me answer of "1" after printing out the warning message and does not say "oh-no" that I want.

What is the proper way to catch these non-fatal autovivification errors? And by the way, is there a nuclear-powered perl6 debugger?

Thank you very much !!!

lisprog

Comment: Related mnemonic: For fatal exceptions, P6 goes CRAZY and prepares to CRASH and you must use `CATCH` to CATCH a CRASH and remember to deal properly with the CRAZY program state if you're CRAZY enough to `.resume`. But for *non*-fatal exceptions P6 remains cool and in control and you can stay cool too, doing nothing, or you can use `CONTROL` for control and use `.resume` when you're done without thinking about it. Concretely, `say 1/0` nets you a CRASH you must CATCH and CRAZY you must handle. `say Any + 1` keeps cool and you don't have to do anything unless you want control with `CONTROL`.

Comment: Thank you very much again, raiph !!! And thanks for the mnemonic :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `quietly` and `CONTROL` instead of `try` and `CATCH`:

```
quietly { say Any + 1; CONTROL { default { say "oh-no" } } }
```

Comment: You don't need the `quietly`, just the `CONTROL` block: `say Any + 1; CONTROL { say "oh-no"; .resume }`

Comment: Thank you Elizabeth Mattijsen !!! I have seen some of your lecture videos on Perl6 on YouTube :-)